# I'm trying to make an timer for resend otp auth code but they didnt show me anything

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I'm trying to create a button that when I click the button. The button text will be changed and start to countdown till the next OTP code time. This is the code that I already tried in my app

```
 bool _isResendAgain = false;

 late Timer _timer;
 int _start = 60;

 void resend() {
       setState(() {
         _isResendAgain = true;
       });
 
       const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
       _timer = new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (timer) {
         setState(() {
           if (_start == 0) {
             _start = 60;
             _isResendAgain = false;
             timer.cancel();
           } else {
             _start--;
           }
         }); 
       });
     }


 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
          Text(
             "Don't receive the OTP?",
                 style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade500),
              ),
           TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                  if (_isResendAgain) return;
                     resend();
                     print(_start.toString()); //the value is 60 when it being printed
                     print(_isResendAgain); // the value is true when it being printed
                    },
              child: Text(
                  _isResendAgain
                     ? "Try again in " + _start.toString()
                     : "Resend",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
         ))
      ],
   ),
```

The countdown function can't be used/didn't show me anything. When I clicked the button it will be the same, and it was "Resend" when I click the button the value is being true and 60 for the second